# how to install QT 5.3.2 version on fedora release 20

Tags: c++, qt

I use `Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug)`, I need `QT` version 5.3.2 and `QMake` version 3.0

so, I try `yum install qt-devel`

and `rpm -qa | grep qt`

```
qt-x11-4.8.6-30.fc20.x86_64
qt-settings-20-18.fc20.noarch
qt5-qtbase-gui-5.2.0-4.fc20.x86_64
qt-devel-4.8.6-30.fc20.x86_64
qt5-qtbase-5.2.0-4.fc20.x86_64
qt-4.8.6-30.fc20.x86_64
```

How to install qt version 5.3.2 and qmake version3.0?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is to go to the QT website and download the package from there. But why do you need an older version? There is a version for linux 5.7.0. Just download the version, probably 5.7.0 for 64bit linux, and then run:

```
chmod +x qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.7.0.run
```

and then `./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.7.0.run`

Keep in mind it needs to be installed as with root permissions so either use sudo or su. Change the working directory after that.

Now if you want specifically this version, you must find the executables and install them from there, i dont know if fedora provides something like that from their package manager.

Comment: good, but I try `./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.3.2.run` but error`cannot connect to x server` this message

Comment: that is a xorg problem, try `export DISPLAY=:0.0` and then execute. If the problem doesnt solve, then it is a permission problem, try granting  access to your user with `xhost +local:root` where root is the user you are granting access to